# Enumerating open tabs in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

I'd like to find a way to enumerate the open tabs (and corresponding URLs) of the open tabs in Internet Explorer. I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112598/enumerate-browser-tabs-from-external-application), which suggests that it's not possible to do this in general, but I'm looking specifically at solutions for IE7 and IE8.

I'd prefer Win32-only solutions (I don't want to take a dependency on .NET, if possible).

I'm open to writing some kind of plugin for Internet Explorer, if that's necessary. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE does not expose a supported way of enumerating tabs.  What you have to do is write a [BHO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250436(VS.85).aspx) that sinks [DWebBrowserEvents2::WindowStateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768307(VS.85).aspx).  Your BHO will be loaded once per tab, and you'll get a WindowStateChanged event whenever the user switches tabs to the old and new tab.  Then you just have to keep a global map of BHOs to Tabs and a pointer to which is the active tab based on WindowStateChanged events.

Note: You can write a toolbar, instead of a BHO, that does the same thing.  Just depends on if you want UI or not.