# Enumerate open Google chrome windows/tabs in delphi

Tags: delphi, browser

I wonder if, and how, it's possible to enumerate all open instances of Chrome..
So let's I have 1 instance of Chrome running with 3 tabs. Stackoverflow, google and youtube.
Is it possible to retrieve that data so you can use the information on that page?

I know how to pull info of a page I just want to know how to get the active chrome windows and pages.

Any ideas?

I've googled on this problem and found some info on [delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com/od/internetintranet/a/webbrowserenum.htm)

I tried it out but it didn't do much, it only showed the instances of explorer.exe.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I'm using Chrome version: 36.0.1985.125.

Comment: You want to do this just for chrome?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well it is my default browser. But if it works for other browsers too thats fine. It's not a requirement to be Chrome specific.

Comment: I guess you first of all need to list all the browsers that you wish to support

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Like I said I use chrome, so that's what i'm after. I just meant that if there is a solution that works on chrome but it also works on firefox that's fine. The goal is to have it work with chrome one way or another.

Comment: [Getting the current tab's URL from Google Chrome using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897070/getting-the-current-tabs-url-from-google-chrome-using-c-sharp) and  [Enumerate browser tabs from external application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112598/enumerate-browser-tabs-from-external-application)

Comment: I recommend that you ask that then. Because there's be a different solution for each browser.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Edited the question. Thanks for that, I had no idea it would be different for each browser.

Comment: How are you pulling info out of a page at the moment?

Comment: Well right now I create a TWebbrowser that navigates to the page I need and I simply extract the source from that page.

Comment: That's a weak way to do it surely. Can't you get the info from the browser?

Comment: Listen to HTTP communication behind. It's naive to believe you'll find a way to support all browsers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well that is what I want to do but I don't know how to get the browser. Which is why I asked this question ;)

Comment: @TLama I dont believe I will find a way. I have no idea what the possibilities are, so when David asked me what browser it was for I said the focus is on Chrome but if it works for other browsers too that would be fine aswell.

Comment: Wishful thinking that you can have one solution fits all by browser automation. Which version of Chrome do you require support for? How you do this depends on the Chrome version. You must include a Chrome version in your question.

Comment: @David, I believe you are thinking of the UI automation. Well, Chrome supports it, but you must enable it first. And that might not be feasible for spyware :-)

Comment: @TLama You are right

Comment: @TeunPronk Chrome extension may well be easiest way to go

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, are there any examples you know off that I can take a look at?

Comment: I'm sure there are. Websearch would be the way to go.

Comment: You might achieve this using same approach as it is shown on delphi.about.com page you refered to. Now the code shown there simply enumerates all shell windows and then checks to see if specific window is of specific interface which is in case of Internet Explorer is declared as iWebBrowser2. So basically for chrome or other browsers you need to find the interface structure that thir windows use and then test all enumerated windows to see if they are of that Interface.

Comment: @SilverWarior Why would other browser windows support any interfaces at all?

Comment: Well why not? Anywhay after some browsing I see that google chrome has its own APi that you can use for this. You can find more info on it here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows

Comment: @SilverWarior My program's main window doesn't support any interfaces that can be queried for. IE is unusual in exposing interfaces like that. It is not the norm.