# active application titles and time spent in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jna

I am using JNA library to get active window titles in Windows OS.
I want to do same in Ubuntu and Mac.
I have tried many options for Ubuntu, but they all need a native tool or service installed before I try to fetch the titles.

I have tried, xdotool, wmctrl, gnome-shell and few more. But I want a similar option which can give me title of application active any time I switch between various.

Comment: Shamless plug: https://github.com/oshi/oshi specifically [getDesktopWindows()](https://www.oshi.ooo/oshi-core-java11/apidocs/com.github.oshi/oshi/software/os/OperatingSystem.html#getDesktopWindows(boolean))

Comment: thanks, it gives the ubuntu desktop window title but for browser tabs like firefox. I opened other applications like calendar, calculated they are not even listed. I passed true and false in getDesktopWindows() method.

Comment: this question is overly broad then, you'll have to deal with each application separately. Your [browser tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112598/enumerate-browser-tabs-from-external-application) desire may not be possible.   JNA just lets you execute native code from Java but you need to find the native API to represent; if one doesn't exist there's not much you can do.